# Getting 401 Unauthorized Error When Attempting to Bulk Export CSV from Crunchbase Despite Authorized API Key

Tags: csv, http-status-code-401

I'm trying to get bulk CSV export from Crunchbase.
According to the documentation (https://data.crunchbase.com/docs/daily-csv-export) you need to paste your API key in this URL:

```
https://api.crunchbase.com/bulk/v4/bulk_export_split.tar.gz?user_key=user_key
```

I have generated my API key in the Crunchbase account https://www.crunchbase.com/account/integrations/crunchbase-api and successfully tested it out on basic requests. Unfortunately when I run the provided query with my `user_key` I get error:

```
[{"status":401,"code":"LA401","message":"Unauthorized user_key"}]
```

The `user_key` is authorized since it was working on other API calls.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Are you using the crunchbase basic api key (odm) or a key associated with the "Enterprise/Applications License"?

If using the basic api key, then the url to download is different, try this. https://api.crunchbase.com/odm/v4/odm.tar.gz?user_key=xxxx

Refer to docs

https://data.crunchbase.com/docs/crunchbase-basic-export
https://data.crunchbase.com/v3.1/docs/open-data-map